# Depth Traversing a graph in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to depth traverse a graph in Python, with 11 nodes.

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
        'B': ['A', 'F'],
        'C': ['D', 'E'],
        'D': ['H', 'J', 'C'],
        'E': ['C', 'F'],
        'F': ['B', 'G'],
        'G': ['F', 'H'],
        'H': ['G', 'D', 'I'],
        'I': ['H', 'K'],
        'J': ['D', 'E', 'K'],
        'K': ['I', 'J']}


current_node = []
viewed_nodes = []
   for i in graph.keys():
    print("I'm at the " + str(i) + " node." + " The nodes connected to " +str(i) + " are " + str(graph[i]))
    print("I'm going to mark the " + str(i) + " node as visited.")
    viewed_nodes.append(str(i))
```

This is my code. I'm trying to figure out how to depth traverse it, meaning go through it all in one line before going back and going down different paths

Comment: Have you looked at graph libraries? They might already have implemented the problem you are trying to solve. E.g. https://github.com/pmatiello/python-graph but there might be others.

Comment: With all due respect, that's not code. It's a dict and two empty lists. What have you actually tried so far?

Comment: for i in graph.keys():
        print("I'm at the " + str(i) + " node.")
        print                            I'm trying to figure out how to make it go down linearly and then go back and fill in what it missed

Comment: add that code to the post, not on a comment @KraeganEpsilon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This below already visits all nodes.

```py
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
        'B': ['A', 'F'],
        'C': ['D', 'E'],
        'D': ['H', 'J', 'C'],
        'E': ['C', 'F'],
        'F': ['B', 'G'],
        'G': ['F', 'H'],
        'H': ['G', 'D', 'I'],
        'I': ['H', 'K'],
        'J': ['D', 'E', 'K'],
        'K': ['I', 'J']}


current_node = []
viewed_nodes = []


def traverse(into):
    if into in viewed_nodes:
        return

    viewed_nodes.append(into)

    for outto in graph[into]:
        if outto not in viewed_nodes:
            traverse(outto)

for node in graph:
    traverse(node)

print(sorted(viewed_nodes))
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
```